# How set project version value in quartz web.xml in <ejb-link> tag

Tags: xml, quartz-scheduler, web.xml

In a scheduled quarcz job, in the web.xml there is given which webmethod of webservice should run.

```
<ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>ejb/LoanClaimTransferWS</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local>com.khb.portal.backend.internal.loandatatransfer.services.LoanClaimTransferWSLocal</local>
        <ejb-link>internal-ejb3-ws-2.1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar#LoanClaimTransferWS</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

But in the ejb-link tag, there is a version of the jar that is changes with every version release. How can the version number set in the web.xml to follow the version changes? I tried:

```
<ejb-link>internal-ejb3-ws-${project.version}.jar#LoanClaimTransferWS</ejb-link>
```

But its generate the exact text given there.

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to set up resource filtering in pom.xml:

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <webResource>
                            <directory>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>web.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </webResource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```